# Invoking a controller method without having a route defined for it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have several routes, and do not want to add another due to the difficulty in setting permissions, etc. I have a controller method, which isn't invoked on any route. Is there any way I can do this in my blade template?

My controller method is as follows:

```
public static function editROA(){
//do stuff
}
```

and in my blade template, I would like to refer this:

```
<a type='button' class='btn-warning' href="{{action('HomeController::editROA')}}">Edit</a>
```

However, this throws an error, and says that there is no method named editROA. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: why you don't want to have route?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik I am restricted to using five routes, assignment rules. Otherwise I would.

Comment: do you have an idea about resource controller and route? that way you can use single route to do CRUD

Comment: i believe it must be `{{action('HomeController@editROA')}}`

Comment: @RaymondNijland nope :/ It gives me the error: `Action App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@editROA not defined. (View: //myview)`

Comment: And if you use `public function editROA(){}`  without the static?

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error, I'm confused how it does not knows which controller I am talking about, but doesnt work for the method

Comment: @bLuke yup my controller is in /app/http/Controllers/HomeController, I have no idea why it ins't working

Comment: The action() helper is looking for a controller action with your route list.  Since you didn't create a route for that action, it's not going to find it.  You also can't create a URL to a controller method without having a route for it, that's what routes are.

Comment: sorry @Muhammad, i was actually trying with already defined routes... it seems laravel can recognize if `action('HomeController@editROA')` is already defined in routes. If it is defined, it works... otherwise it returns same error you're facing. mb

Comment: @rexw so there is no way to do something like this?

Comment: @bLuke yea don't worry about it, the approach I am trying to implement is unorthodox to say the least.

Comment: @Muhammad, I'm telling you without route its not possible and you can only do resource controller to do what you want to do, only 5 routes.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik ahhh I see. Yea i'll look into it, I apologise for not looking earlier, I thought that maybe there was a way.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik so in resourceful routes (Laravel 5.0), I still would have to create a route no?

Comment: yeah, you've to create route but one route will handle so many stuffs, like add, edit, delete, show etc

Comment: Actually Route::resource will create various DIFFERENT routes. Not only one route that will handle different stuff. You can check the routes that it creates with the command "php artisan route:list" after you've implemented it.

Comment: An easy way I could see to do this without creating more routes, is to use query strings with an existing route, and if a certain field is present in the query string, return the result of a different method from within the controller.

Comment: is your issue solved?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik, yea I resorted to using an additional parameter in the url, and based on that I would direct the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot have more than five routes, I would suggest you use only one wild-carded route. So you run an if else on the wild card to call the appropriate method.

```
Route::get('{uri?}',function($uri){
    if($uri == "/edit")
    {
        return app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@editROA');
    }else if($uri == "something else"){
        return app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@someMethod');
    }
    // add statements for other routes
});
```

**view**

```
<a type='button' class='btn-warning' href="{{url('edit')}}">Edit</a>
```